# Setting a default value for the current cell Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

It seems its possible to conditionally fill the value of other cells based on the value from other cell. However I would like to say, if I have not entered any information to a cell it displays a `0`

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(D2), "", 0))
```

or

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D2), "", "Default Value")
```

But this will return `#REF!` error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can do this but not directly.

for your range from the image C2:E you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(C2:E*1)
```

but this formula needs to be used in row 2 in any empty column which isnt C, D or E column. after that you can hide the C:D columns and use visual only from the arrayformula

[image]

Comment: Humm ye, so it is not possible to do what I am after then. It seems?

Comment: @JamieHutber https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j-0deRLr8aBlXpkiAsW7m1UqKJNdimlyqypcYBJPe9c/edit#gid=272556832

Answer (score 0):

You can't calculate D2 value with D2 value...
You can't use D2 in the formula.

a better approach will be having another column (E2) that will be defined by:

```
E2 formula:
=IF(ISBLANK(D2), "", "Default Value")
```

Comment: Ye, that is very sad. As I would like a default value for my cells so I do not need to enter 0 on them all :p